# Missing get() in Peewee RawQuery

Tags: python, peewee

I have a function that creates the `where` and the `words` variables, then executes a raw query with Peewee.

I would expect this to work:

```
Project.raw('select count(id) as np from project where' + where, *words).get().np
```

But when I try it I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'RawQuery' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Instead I need to iterate through that one element, create a list and get its first item to get it to work:

```
list(Project.raw('select count(id) as np from project where' + where, *words))[0].np
```

Is there a reason why `get()` is missing from `RawQuery()`?

Is there a cleaner way to get the result of my raw query?

**EDIT**

It is a poor man text search: I am looking for all the words typed, in any order, in the fields `name` and `number`.

Ajax calls are generated as the user types on a text input field. The calls send the `text` being typed and the server returns the first `MAX_RESULTS` items and the total number of available items.

Here is the code that uses the hack:

```
words = ['%%%s%%' % i for i in text]
where = ' and '.join(['(name like ? or number like ?)'] * len(words))
words = [w for l in zip(words, words) for w in l]
n_results = list(DbProject.raw('select count(number) as count from dbproject where' + where, *words))[0].count
projects = DbProject.raw('select * from dbproject where' + where + ' order by number desc limit ' + str(MAX_RESULTS), *words)
```

I know there are better ways to do [text search with SQLite](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/search/?q=sqlite%20text%20search), but the text search in this project has such a small importance that I decided to spend as little time as possible on it. Still, I didn't like it and I decided to ask.

Comment: I would be quite willing to bet that Peewee can generate the appropriate SQL for you, so you don't have to place hacks like ".raw()" in your codebase.

Comment: @coleifer I added some details to the post about my use case.